# Quick edit with custom twig templates

Tags: theming, 8, entities

I am trying to get quick edit to work in combination with my twig templates where i only print out specific fields like this:

```
{{content.field_teaser_overline}}
```

The rendered markup of the field looks like this

```
<div data-quickedit-field-id="node/21/field_teaser_overline/de/full" class="field field--name-field-teaser-overline field--type-string field--label-hidden field__item quickedit-field">Overline</div>
```

What i figured out for now is that it must look like the following to actually work

```
<div data-quickedit-field-id="node/21/field_teaser_url/de/full" class="field field--name-field-teaser-url field--type-link field--label-hidden field__item quickedit-field quickedit-candidate quickedit-editable">http://www.google.de</div>
```

So the classes:

```
quickedit-candidate quickedit-editable
```

are missing.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The classes are not in the drupal rendered markup, but are added in backbone FieldDecorationView.js. Can you check, if your browser loads this library (when js aggregate switched off)?

Comment: Yeah it is loaded, I am able to quick edit my content when I print it out completly with {{ content }}. So it has do be wrong something with my template.

Comment: There is an issue with blocks, when printing single fields, that the cache tags are missing. You could have a similar problem with nodes and quickedit. The two classes are not the cause of the problem, because their are added in js. You would try to make a diff with js disabled, to see what else is missing.