# Getting quick edit to work for custom fields in templates

Tags: theming, 8

I have some custom content types and have made custom templates for them. I need to get the quick edit functionality working with the text fields on these custom templates, as it doesn't currently. I can't find very much information about this - can anyone give me some pointers about how I go about this?

Comment: Trying a guess here, based on [Quick edit with custom twig templates](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/215005/quick-edit-with-custom-twig-templates)  add `quickedit-candidate quickedit-editable` at the end of your current class using your web browser (Inspect) and see if that enables it.